# Pegar atributos de div pai através de de elementos filhos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu possuo **várias** estruturas que seguem um estilo único:

```
<div data-id="1">
 <div>
   <button>Descobrir é o data-id desta estrutura</button> 
 </div>
</div>
```

com jQuery ou JavaScript como eu poderia obter o `data-id` *(1)* da div através do `click` no `button`?

Comment: `$('button').parent().parent().data('id');`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sugiro usares o [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) assim:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var target = $(this).closest('[data-id]');
    alert(target.data('id'));
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5t59xu5f/

O `.closest()` sobe no DOM à procura do primeiro elemento que o seletor indica/procura. O seletor `'[data-id]'` quer dizer "um elemento com o atributo `data-id`, independentemente do seu valor, desde que tenha o atributo".

Desse modo evitas código do tipo `.parent().parent()` que é dificil de manter e saber a que elemento se aplica.

Comment: Boa, sem contar que em uma futura manutenção de HTML e possível inserção de um novo nível de DIV, não precisará dar manutenção no JS também adicionando um novo _.parent()_.

Comment: Dei meu positivo e marcação correta por esse fato de não precisar de uma manutenção em conjunto caso seja necessário, achei mais limpo de trabalhar, fora que não conhecia essa função, +1 pro meu aprendizado, obrigada!!!

Comment: como esse `.closest()` se comporta dentro do `onclick="fun(event)"`?

`function fun(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.closest('[data-id]'));`
Diz que o closest é uma função.

Comment: @ThomsonTorvalds se estás a usar o `e` deves fazer `e.target.closest(...etc` em JS nativo ou `$(e.target).closest(` com jQuery

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira usando `parent()` e depois `data()`:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().data('id'));
});
```

Comment: E se tiver várias div's dentro uma da outra, eu tenho que usar o `parent()` o tanto de vezes que eu tenho uma div?

Comment: Sim, `parent()` é referente ao nível, para cada `div` deve ter um `parent()`.

Comment: Sugiro a leitura: http://jquerybrasil.org/uso-dos-metodos-parent-parents-ou-closest/

Comment: @LuisHenrique boa referência, realmente o uso de `closest` facilita bastante.