# Multiplicando input criador pelo for

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse script onde eu criei o for para aparecer todos os registro contidos no banco de dados onde o todos os produtos com o mesma categoria aparecer (mostra nome e valor)

e o cliente clica a quantidade desejada e o valor aparece ao clicar aparece o resulado e depois envia para o banco de dados

Porem ao clicar na quantidade do primeiro produto a mutiplicacao e feita so que o resultado aparece em todos as outras tabelas e quanto eu clico na quantidade da segunda tabela a multiplicacao nao e feita e ainda mantem o resultado do primeiro produto isso acontece com o terceiro e o quarto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*** como fazer cada um se mutiplicar e aparecer seu resultado. ***

```
<?php
public function listarProduto($sql){
$total = $this->totalRegistros($sql);

for($j=0;$j<$total_prod;$j++){
    $this-> verTudo($sql,$j);

    $sqlRegistro = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlRegistro);
    $idProduto = mysql_result($result, 0, "idProduto");
    $idNomeProduto = mysql_result($result, 0, "idNomeProduto");
    $valor  = mysql_result($result, 0, "valor");
    $action = "op/opcadastro.php";

echo "
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#valor, #qtde').click(function(){
           var valor = $('input[name=valor]').val(); 
           var qtde        = $('#qtde').val(); 

           if(valor == '') valor = 0;
           if(qtde == '') qtde = 0;

          var result = ((valor) * (qtde)).toFixed(2);
          $('.resultado').html(result.replace('.',',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, '$1.'));
          });
       });
</script>

<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='tabela'>
<tr><td>Nome do Produto</td>
<td>$idNome</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Quantidade</td>
<td><input type='number' id='qtde' name='qtde'></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Valor</td>
<td><input type='hidden' id='qtde' name='qtde'> $valor</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Resultado</td>
<td><span class='resultado'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'>
<form action='$action' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <input type='hidden' name='idProduto' value='$idProduto'/>
<input type='hidden' name='qtde' value='$qtde'/>
<input type='hidden' name='valor' value='$valor'/>
<input type='hidden' name=acao value='INSERIR' />
                    <input type='submit' value='Adicionar à Lista'>
                        </form></td></tr>
                    </table>";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: olhando por auto a primeira coisa que eu vi foi que você possui dois campos com o id=qtde

Answer (score 3):

Tens de usar classes ou outro atributo em vêz de IDs duplicadas. Isso é html inválido. O JavaScript não sabe em que parte do DOM (html) está a correr por isso usar ID nos seletores vai sempre retornar o primeiro elemento encontrado e só esse. A razão porque todos os resultados são re-escritos é por causa de `$('.resultado').html(...)` que procura todas as classes e muda o valor. Tens de procurar só o `'.resultado'` dessa tabela em que clicaste.

Outra coisa que não faz sentido é gerares JavaScript dentro de um loop de PHP. Podes mudar o JavaScript para ser independente do numero de linhas ou quantidade de tabelas, somente usando classes e a relação do DOM (usando o [`.closest()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78396/129)) para saber como encontrar o que queres e calcular.

Muda todos os `id='qtde'` para `class='qtde'` (ou juntando a classe `qtde` ás classes existentes caso já haja) e depois usa o JavaScript assim (só uma vez no documento):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qtde').click(function() {
        var table = $(this).closest('table');
        var valor = table.find('input[name="valor"]').val() || 0;
        var qtde = this.value || 0; // saber o valor do elemento clicado, dando zero caso não tenha valor
        var result = (valor * qtde).toFixed(2);
        var finalResult = result.replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, '$1.');
        table.find('.resultado').html(finalResult);
    });
});
```

Repara ainda que o jQuery retorna-te valores em formato *String*. O ideal era converteres para inteiros e não confiares nas conversões de Tipos em JavaScript. Assim sugeria fazeres:

```
 var result = (parseInt(valor, 10) * parseInt(qtde, 10)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: +1 por explicar `id` e `class`

Comment: gostei da sua ajuda. intendi sua explicação e coloquei algumas coisas